# Stopping function event firing a second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently trying to trigger an event on a mouse click where the user clicks a button and it triggers an event, once the user clicks on an input field, Please see code below or jsFiddle Below:-

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $('*').css( 'cursor', 'crosshair' );
    $('input').one("click",function (event) {
        alert(event.pageX, event.pageY);
    });
});
```

I have an example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nkw6m9eh/1/)

The issue that I am having is once the user clicks in the input field the function needs to stop/finish. But instead the if the user click the second input field after clicking the initial one it runs the function again.

I have attempted putting

```
return false;
```

Inside the code to stop further propagation but this has not worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you wanting to stop propagation or are you wanting to stop the event firing a second time?  If the former, have a look at https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/, if the latter, then look at using http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: I want the event to stop firing a second time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove eventlistener after you click once on the input field. something like this:

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $('*').css( 'cursor', 'crosshair' );
    $('input').one("click",function (event) {
        alert(event.pageX, event.pageY);
        $('input').off('click');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use event like this:

```
$('.myBtn').on('click', function(event)
{
    event.stopPropagation();
})
```

this stops all event propagation linked with the event handler. More information can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: This is still running the function once I click in the second input field.

Comment: @TonyHensler that's because you have a click event inside a click event - they should be separate..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var buttonClicked = false;
$('.button').click(function () {
    $('*').css( 'cursor', 'crosshair' );
    buttonClicked = true;
});
$('input').one("click",function (event) {
    if (buttonClicked)
    {
       buttonClicked = false;
       alert(event.pageX, event.pageY);
    }
});
```